# A simple doubt in number theory problem for an even number,

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I considered an even number $n\geq 9$, where it is divisible by some positive integer $k$.

Also, $k$ does *not* divide $\frac{n}{2}\ $ (negation of the hypothesis in my [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184984/a-simple-doubt-in-number-theory-problem)).

Let $n = kq$.

Can we say that $q$ is even in this case? Can anyone help to get it theoretically? 
Thanks a lot for the help.

**My attempt:**

Let $n = kq$.

Since $k$ does not divide $\frac{n}{2}$, we have

$n/2 = k.q_1 + r$ for $0<r\leq k-1$.

How to conclude the even or odd property of $k$ and $q$ here?

Comment: This is not clear.  Say $k=n$.  Then of course $k$ divides $n$, $k$ does not divide $\frac n2$ but $q=1$ is odd.  Is that a counterexample to your claim?

Comment: Try a couple of examples. What if $n=10$? Or $12$? What can $k$ possibly be? What can $q$ possibly be?

Comment: Strongly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184984/a-simple-doubt-in-number-theory-problem

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed, so I changed my comment, thanks @lulu

Comment: @Dirk  Though the question with this assumption ($k\,\nmid \,\frac n2$) doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @monalisa  Can you clarify your question?  As stated there is no difficulty coming up with counterexamples.  I assume that you intended something else?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it not clear what you are asking.  As stated, the desired claim is clearly false.  If you intended something else, please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Follows immediately from my answer in your prior question, namely by **divisor** $\rm\color{#c00}{recip}\color{#0a0}{rocity}\ % divisor reciprocity $ 
 $$ {\rm If} \ \,\rm\ \large 2,K\mid N\ \ \  {\rm then} \ \ \rm\,\ \color{#c00}K\ {\LARGE \mid} {\large  \frac{N}{\color{#0a0}2}}\! \iff{\large \color{#0a0}2}\ {\LARGE \mid} {\large \frac{N}{\color{#c00}K}}\!=\!Q\,\  [\rm\!\!\iff\!\  2K\mid N\,]$$  Thus $\,\rm Q\,$ is even $\!\rm \iff\! K\mid N/2,\,$ which *by hypothesis* is false here, and true in your prior question. This is just the negation of your prior question.

Comment: @BillDubuque So, since this is negation, we can say that $q$ has to be odd. Am I right in concluding so?

Comment: Yes. negating the above $\ \rm Q\ is\ \color{#c00}{not}\ even\iff K\color{#c00}\nmid N/2,\,$ i.e. $\rm K$ does $\rm\color{#c00}{\rm not}$ divide $\rm N/2\,$. But this indivisibility is true *by hypothesis*, thus $\rm Q$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

As a counter example, take $n = 14$ and $k = 2$. Then $2$ does not divide $14/2  = 7$ and $q = 7$ is not an even number.

Comment: I tried numerically but theoretically, I am unable to prove it.

Comment: @monalisa: You can't prove it because it's false. You must *disprove* it, which means giving a (numerical) counterexample.

Comment: @CameronBuie Actually we can do better than a single counterexample, we can prove that it is always false, i.e. $q$ is always odd - see my comment on the question.

Comment: @Bill: Fair point